# In Eclipse , I am using Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0) ,getting maven build error related to JDK8 which is already set

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, java-8

> method references are not supported in -source 1.5
> (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)
> [ERROR]

The JDK path 8 is clearly set in `eclipse` but `maven` build is getting failure

`Eclipse Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)`

I am using `Maven/Java8/Spring MVC`

The error message:

> /C:/MyFolder/MyCodeStuff/Changes/Implementations/MyAppProject/MyApp/spring-mvc-example/src/main/java/com/journaldev/spring/controller/ManageFilesController.java:[520,100] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
> [ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

Comment: Try Alt+F5 (or right-click on the project, Maven -> Update Project). If that does nothing, please show us your POM file. If you try to build your project from the CLI, using `mvn clean verify`, what happens then?

Comment: You have to set the source code Java version in your `pom.xml`: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html